# Vertices deforming although ungrouped (weight painting)

Tags: weight-painting

Although I have specifically removed the problematic vertices from the hand vertex group they still deform with this bone. You can see the deformations in the first image below.

[image]
Blend file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47788

Can anyone tell me what is sausing this issue and how to solve it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the file: nothing is wrong in the hand bones, but remember that if mesh deforms something else **must** have weights for it.

In this case is (at least) another bone - maybe you selected it inadvertently while assigning weights to the hand mesh.

See how: you start with this

[image]

but moving "UpperLeg.R" bone, you see how hand fingers deform

[image]

so while you move the "intended bone" (Hand.R), the distance form "UpperLeg.R" changes and thus the deform influcence, so you get those strange deforms...

hth

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me greatly in understanding how weights actually work.